# rails cucumber step definition: how to deal with select_input

Tags: selenium, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using cucumber + selenium chromedriver in my application.

I'm building the post create scenario of CRUD

In the step_definition, I have to fill the form with input_field and select_field (option).

In case of input_field, I do:

```
When("I fill in email with {string}") do |string|
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: string
end
```

In case of select_field, what should I do?

This is the view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 required-field">
    <label>Permission</label>
    <%= f.collection_select(:user_role_id, UserRole.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

So basically, this is the code with Capybara:

```
find('#mySelectFildId').find(:xpath, 'option[myNumberOption]').select_option
```